What does 'ex' mean in this context
I'm currently working with sanction lists of the EU—e.g., https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/DE/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02006R0765-20240701#tocId2.
There are tables of products which should not be exported such as:



CN Code
Description




88
Aircraft, spacecraft, and parts thereof


ex 2710 19 83
Hydraulic oils for the usage in vehicles of Chapter 88


ex 2710 19 99
Other lubricating oils and other oils for use in aviation



I always interpreted the "ex" as "not in the exact wording". So that if I want to export an oil that states that it is made for generators but could be used for planes, then it is sanctioned.
Questions:

Am I right with my interpretation?
What does "ex" literally mean in this context?


It is the Latin "ex" meaning "from."  In this case, it means "a subset of."  Category 2710 19 83, for example, is "hydraulic oils," but the prohibition applies only to those hydraulic oils that are for vehicles classified in chapter 88, namely aircraft and spacecraft.  The prohibition here, therefore, does not extend to hydraulic oils intended for use in, for example, farming equipment.
(CN refers to the "common nomenclature," and in some tables of the document linked in the question, you will find this link to the document that sets it out: https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=OJ:L:2021:385:FULL&from=EN).

+1 though this does not address the "dual use" issue that hydraulic oils, lubricating oils, and other other oils are produced to meet specifications rather than for particular uses and most have multiple potential uses.  There are specific "dual use" rules such as at https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02021R0821-20231216

@Henry the question is about the meaning of "ex."  Whether any given oil is covered or not by this provision is beyond the scope of the question and therefore of this answer.

ex also is for "formerly" in regards to ship names, either due to renaming or retirement of the ship. It can also indicate changes of owner. Some exaples: the "Ex-USS Chancellorsville" is the USS Robert Smalls due to renaming,  Likewise the Ex-Rio de Janeiro from Brazil became Ex-Sultan Osman-ı Evvel from the Ottoman and ended as HMS Agincourt from the UK.

@Trish "ex" is also used rather prominently in EU law to mean "former" when referring to various provisions of the EU treaties.  But the question is "What does 'ex' mean in this context," and, in this context, it doesn't mean "former."
